# Create pop-up announcements upon login?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to get all of my users to see announcements. As you already know, we can't force everyone to use a dashboard that would have the announcements located in it as outlined here: https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/11/22/adding-announcements-to-the-dashboard-in-crm-2011/. I could add this component to the most frequently-used dashboards, but I'm not going to get complete compliance. Too many people use user-defined dashboards and views. Further, not all of our users use email or other correspondence consistently, so my channels of communication for updates to the system are limited. My best bet was to create a popup upon login containing announcements, akin to the "pending email" warning, which would appear upon login regardless of any other conditions:
[image]

I've dug around to try and see where that warning comes from, in hopes of reverse engineering it to build a new component... but I just couldn't figure it out. I've seen options on how to disable or circumvent it, which naturally is the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a missing most wanted piece/feature even today in latest 365 versions.

We are using Web resources in global dashboards to socialize such thing, as announcements are deprecated. We cannot circumvent personal dashboards as default scenario.

We are planning to explore Learning path for this requirement, but that’s not applicable for your version.